# Panamanian citizen living in the US lost his Panamanian passport

Tags: visas, usa, passports, panama

A friend of mine who is a Panamanian citizen lives and works in the US. He recently lost his passport with his US vIsas in it. He currently has no other photo ID except a Panamanian drivers license.

Can he get a new passport from Panama without having to return to the country?

A trip to the Panamanian consulate yielded no definite answer, and the topic is causing considerable stress for the guy, so any advice or leads would be much appreciated.

Comment: Presumably the only way to get a passport within the US is through the Panamanian consulate; if they can't help, I don't know how anyone else can.  Maybe he should try to escalate within the consulate, or contact the embassy in Washington?

Comment: Can you provide us details about the indefinite answer(s) he did get?

Comment: How will he return to Panama without a valid travel document?

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways, and it'll depend on how long he has in the US.

1) He can apply for a new passport, from America, through the Consulate. For example, the [Consulate of Panama in Houston, Texas](http://www.conpahouston.com/consular-visas.php) states that it's possible to do so and how to do it, including the requisite forms and costs.  The downside is that it takes 6-8 weeks, which may be too long for him.

This is confirmed on the pages of the [Consulate in Toronto, Canada](http://www.consulatepanama.com/index.php/consular-services/passports-and-application-for-panamanian-passport.html), the [Consulate in Los Angeles](http://www.consulateofpanamalosangeles.com/consulate-of-panama/) and even the [one in the UK](http://www.panamaconsul.co.uk/index.php?page=faqs&hl=en_US) suggests 10 weeks!

2) The second option is to, according to the [UK consulate](http://www.panamaconsul.co.uk/index.php?page=faqs&hl=en_US) 'apply for a travel document'.  This is vague, but I'd take it to be like an Emergency Travel Document that New Zealand has for citizens who have lost their passports overseas - it's like a pseudo-passport, generally only available for a short trip (usually back home).

For this I'd recommend trying the consulate again, or contacting the [Panamanian Passport Office](http://www.pasaporteordinario.gob.pa/) back in Panama for information on this 'travel document'.

These are recognised by most countries, including the one he's in - the [Department of Homeland Security insists you have either a valid passport, or 'an emergency travel document issued by an embassy or consulate.'](http://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/agency/useful-resources/travel-document-requirements.html)